# Why does tkinter frame expand along the bottom but creates blank space above in parent frame when parent frame is dragged larger?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have the following (Extracts) from my code:

```
# Class called by createWidgets

class dispRadio(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **options):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, **options)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(expand=NO, side=TOP)
        
        # other stuff dpne here
 
# Class called by main body

class NewMenu(Frame):                                   # an extended frame
    def __init__(self, parent=None):    # attach to top-level
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.main = self.master
        
        # other stuff done here, e.g. set variable for pandastable dataframe
        
        self.createWidgets()                       # attach frames/widgets
        
        self.PandasFrame = Frame(self.main, highlightbackground="green", highlightthickness=3) 
        self.PandasFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        self.pt = Table(self.PandasFrame, dataframe = catagory_receipts, width=1500, maxcellwidth=1500)
        self.pt.show()   
        
    def createWidgets(self):    
        self.mainWin = dispRadio(self, highlightbackground="blue", highlightthickness=1)
        self.smallWin = dispRadio2(self, highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=1)

# Main Body

root = Tk()
nm = NewMenu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This creates a button widget followed by the frame containing the pandastable, When I drag on the bottom of the main window, the pandastable window does increase the number of rows shown at the bottom of the frame; however, empty blank space is created between the buttons widget and the padnadstable frame. I would have expected the top of the pandastable frame to remain just below the buttons widgets and the growth only at the bottom of the frame. My question is why does the parent frame grow space (between the button widgets and the pandastable frame and not be filled by the pandastable frame?

I have tried various methods of packing and ordering of the frames, but I can't seem to find a way for the resizing of the main window to not grow empty space between the other frames instead of the frame filling the new space above it.

[Example of frames before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGfRw.png)

Tried different methods of packing (fill, expand, sidew) or order of frame packing in parent. Also looked through pandastable documentation to see if it had anything to control it's parent frame but didn't find anything.

Comment: I get an error when I run the code: `NameError: name 'dispRadio2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'dispRadio'?` If I fix that I get `NameError: name 'Table' is not defined`

Comment: It wasn’t a complete program just the relevant parts creating the frames and packing them to keep the example short. dispradio2 was almost identical to dispradio so I left it out for brevity as well as the data frame put in the pandastable as it wasn’t relevant to the question. Acw1668 answered it and solved my problem with just the pieces I provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have configured both `nm` (instance of `NewMenu`) and `self.PandasFrame` (instance of `Frame` that holds `self.pt`) to fill the available space of the main window (as they are both created as children of the main window).

If you want only `self.PandasFrame` to be resized when the main window is resized, change

```py
self.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
```

to

```py
self.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
```

inside `NewMenu.__init__()`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, works great. It now makes perfect sense. I will go back an reread the relevant tkinter chapters in Programming Python about packing frames inside of frames and how to control fill and expand sop I can figure it out myself next time.

Comment: Update, my confusion was I thought using self.master (main) for the parent frame of self.PandaFrame would make it contained under the frame of the NewMenu class and not under the main window. I thought I had even tried x  = Frame.__init__(self, parent) and passing x into the creation of PandaFrame but it didn't change the behavior. In any event. not filling the Y axis of the PandasFrame makes sense now.